# How to read parquet files into tables in Java using Apache Arrow?

Tags: apache-arrow

I want to do the same like `pq_table = pq.read_table(file_path)` in pyarrow.

I tried Arrow 8.0.0 with the examples from here but it does not work.
https://arrow.apache.org/cookbook/java/dataset.html#query-parquet-file

The `forEachRemaining` is missing in Arrow 8.0.0.

Context: I want to read sparse columns into CSR/BSR format for fast sequential access later.