# How to get an efficient data ingestion solution using Java, Apache Arrow and Apache Parquet

Tags: parquet, apache-arrow, parquet-mr, apache-arrow-datafusion

I'm working on a **data lake** solution for an **IoT framework** that does 44Khz data acquisition for a few dozen sensors (~990.000 measures/seconds).

**I would like suggestions** on how to get an **efficient data ingestion solution** using Java 11+, Apache Arrow and Apache Parquet .

For data ingestion I am currently using the AvroParquetWriter implementation at https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr and **I would like to partition** the dataset using two fields: timestamp and sensor name.

I'm not finding examples of creating partitioned datasets in this API.

I can switch from `AvroParquetWriter`. Furthermore, the solution does not need to support distributed clustered processing. Just separating the partitions into different directories on the local filesystem is enough.

By the way, I currently use DataFusion to query datasets writed by AvroParquetWriter. Data ingestion performance is satisfactory. My interest in partitioning the data serves the purpose of improving query performance.

Regards

Comment: related question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72233354/how-to-read-parquet-files-into-tables-in-java-using-apache-arrow

Comment: It sounds like you have a partial? solution at this point. Do you have any data on the performance that you see now?

Comment: Hi @L.Blanc, Data Ingestion performance is satisfactory. My interest in partitioning the data serves the purpose of improving query performance.